# Where is Python's coroutine type defined?

Tags: python, async-await, python-3.4, python-3.5, python-asyncio

I'm working on Python 3.5.1 and I want to be able to tell if a function has returned as coroutine object but I cannot find where the coroutine type is defined, instead as of late I've been using the below snippet to get the type through instantiating a coroutine with a function.

```
async def _f():
    pass
COROUTINE_TYPE = type(_f())
```

There's got to be a better way to do this, my question is where is this type defined so I can use it directly?

Comment: have you tried `from typing import Coroutine`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably the best way to access the coroutine type is through the [`types`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.CoroutineType) module:

```
import types

types.CoroutineType  # here it is
```

That's not actually where the coroutine type is *defined* - `types.py` does pretty much the same thing you're doing to get at it - but it's the standard Python-level way to *access* the type.

If you want to see the actual definition of the type, that's in [`Include/genobject.h`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Include/genobject.h) and [`Objects/genobject.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/genobject.c#l849). Look for the parts that say `PyCoroWhatever` or `coro_whatever`.

Comment: There we go! For some reason I didn't think to try `types.CoroutineType`, I had already tried `types.Coroutine` and then gave up when I shouldn't have. Thanks!

Comment: @Oasiscircle: Next time, also try `dir(types)` to get a list of everything in the module (or `help(types)` for more useful, better-formatted information, but `help(types)` in this case doesn't tell you what you want to know).

Comment: @DietrichEpp Haha don't worry, I know about `dir()` and `help()`, I've been programming Python professionally for a while now. ;)

Comment: @Oasiscircle: I'm not questioning your competency, just giving information for future visitors to the site.

Comment: There's no `CoroutineType` class in that module in Python 3.7.1

Comment: @OlegSilkin: I'm going to guess you looked in `typing` instead of `types`. `types.CoroutineType` is a thing that exists. `typing.CoroutineType` does not exist.

Comment: this seems to to work too: `isinstance(my_coroutine(), Coroutine)
<input>:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'my_coroutine' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
True` using `from typing import Coroutine`

Comment: what is wrong with `from typing import Coroutine`?

Comment: @CharlieParker: First off, that's not the actual runtime coroutine type. It's a type hint for objects that provide a coroutine-compatible interface. Second, the earlier user was trying to access `typing.CoroutineType`, not `typing.Coroutine`, and `typing.CoroutineType` doesn't exist at all.

Comment: @user2357112 so which one is the proper one I should be using?

Comment: @CharlieParker: Depends on what you're doing. If you're writing type hints, you should use `collections.abc.Coroutine`, or `typing.Coroutine` on older Python versions. If you want to do an `isinstance` check, you probably shouldn't actually use `isinstance` - you should probably use [`asyncio.iscoroutine`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=iscoroutine#asyncio.iscoroutine), which detects both `async def` coroutines and generator-based coroutines. If you still want to do an isinstance check, you should use `types.CoroutineType`.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to tell if a function is a coroutine is with [`asyncio.iscoroutinefunction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.iscoroutinefunction).

```
asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(some_func)
```

Comment: Thanks! This happens to solve my current problem but doesn't really answer the question directly, because if I want to know where the coroutine type is defined, not how to check a function if it will return a coroutine.

Comment: `asyncio.iscoroutine` does `isinstance(obj, _COROUTINE_TYPES)`, where the TYPES is defined in `asyncio.coroutines.py` as 2 or 3 types.

Comment: what is wrong with `from typing import Coroutine`?

Comment: @CharlieParker that is meant for static type checking, not runtime usage.

Answer (score 2):

If you use something like pycharm it is easy to due to autocomple to get it without knowing it of the top of your head e.g.

```
from typing import Coroutine
isinstance(my_coroutine(), Coroutine)
```

output:

```
<input>:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'my_coroutine' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
True` using
```

not sure what the difference with `CoroutineType` is however or if it matters.

---

all code:

```
"""
"""

import asyncio
from asyncio.events import AbstractEventLoop

import time

from typing import Coroutine

async def expensive_io(msg_to_io_device: str = '') -> str:
    await asyncio.sleep(2.5)  # simulating expensive io
    return f'expensive io done {msg_to_io_device}'

async def my_coroutine():
    result1: str = await expensive_io()
    print(f'{result1=}')
    result2: str = await expensive_io()
    print(f'{result2=}')
    result3: str = await expensive_io()
    print(f'{result3=}')

def test1():
    """
    Single coroutine that waits a couple of times but since the event loop has nothing else to do it is forced to wait.

    Learned from this example: you *have* to await a routine that is a asyncio coroutine e.g. with the async keyword.
    This is interesting because it means that calling a async function actually creates a coroutine (in python it
    creates a generator).
    """
    # - run event loop
    event_loop: AbstractEventLoop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    coroutines = [my_coroutine()]
    event_loop.run_until_complete(*coroutines)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #
    test1()

    print('Success, done!\a')
```

see this for a complete example and explanation: https://github.com/brando90/ultimate-utils/blob/d104bd06135113498c84e830e91ba77f413c66cd/tutorials_for_myself/concurrency/asyncio_my_example.py#L87

Answer (score 0):

Python's coroutine type is defined in [`_collections_abc`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/_collections_abc.py), which is imported in [`collections.abc`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/collections/abc.py), which itself is imported in [asyncio.coroutines](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/coroutines.py).

Not sure how this helps you more than @dirn's answer though (which is how to tell if a function is a coroutine).

Comment: @Oasiscircle: That's not actually the coroutine type. It's an ABC for types that implement an interface matching that of coroutines. This is similar to how `collections.abc.Set` isn't the set type.

Comment: @user2357112 I was mostly looking for something to use with `isinstance`, and an interface fits that bill. If there's a place where the coroutine object that implements that interface then I guess that would be more appropriate.

Comment: what is wrong with `from typing import Coroutine`?